# Is there some trick for Bootstrap to define desktop, tablets and mobiles from each others rather than plain screen size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to optimize my lay out as responsive as possible, but I've bumped into weird problem; despite my iPhone and iPad Mini are showing to be two different sized platforms according Bootstraps' site, yet while making edits on my lay out, they both seem to interpret the lay out in sm-size.

How I can get it so that Bootstrap understands that small screen with 960 px screen is no suitable for sidebar without effing up desktops and tablets?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap provides exact media queries here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries .  With a 960 px screen you would have to alter this to fit this exact resolution.  When you hit desktops and larger, the same would apply to adjust the media query/css.

You're able to customize these media queries and CSS to fit your needs a few ways:

- Customizing Bootstrap and compiling and downloading the results thru the 'Customize' section http://getbootstrap.com/customize/
- Creating custom Media Queries/CSS to right over the default Bootstrap Media Queries/CSS rules.  This can be done with regular .css file, Less or Sass (see 1st url for grid table that outlines pixel dimensions for different media size(s)).

It seems the default media queries are working fine for your iPhone and iPad Mini - and as the default for Bootstrap is mobile first, the sm-col class prefix would make this work likely how you want (I am assuming I am reading your statement properly).

Post a follow-up to see if this helps and/or more detail can be provided.

*I hope I've helped and/or guided you in the proper direction (this is my first question I'm answering, be kind :-)).*

Comment: (Sorry, too fast enter finger!)

Yeah, I checked out already Customize-section, I'm just tad worried that 960 px is too much, not alone that it's not then enough for newer iPhones/other tall and thin phones. And I really would like the layout to work on portrait phone (standard Wordpress, with one sidebar). :/

Can I teach it somehow to recognize it's a phone or tablet specifically with Sass/Less or even CSS?

Comment: Responsive design is challenging in editing code, but fun!  http://viewportsizes.com is a good list of screen sizes with portrait and horizontal orientation(just shows crazy number of possibilities).  I'd still recommend changing Media Queries/CSS for what you want. Bootstrap handles CSS(esp. Less/Sass) and it's easy/efficient to edit.  I don't have source to point to, but "sniffing" for specific device(s), while possible, has own challenges (i.e., some devices won't be recognized as a phone or tablet as one example).  Hope that helps!